# How to create a Delphi Android Application APK to include files

Tags: android, delphi

How do you include files and/or folders containing files with an Android application APK file. The Delphi run process wipes the contents of the Assets directory and the files/folders I placed there are not included in the APK package. I assume you must manually add System.StartupCopy to your .DRP unit to copy the files and/or folders to path specified by TPath.GetDocumentsPath().

Answer (score 6):

Use the **Project->Deployment** main menu item, which allows you to put files into the installation and specify the location for them after install. See **Deploying Your Final Android Application** in the [Android Mobile Application Development](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Android_Mobile_Application_Development) topic in the documentation.

Clicking through a little will get you to [Preparing an Android Application for Deployment](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Preparing_an_Android_Application_for_Deployment), which has a step-by-step list on configuring the options for deploying the app:

> You must configure several options for your Android app before you build the application for distribution. The properties that you configure are bundled with your application, in the AndroidManifest.xml file. You cannot modify these properties after you build and sign your application. Because these properties provide key information about your application, you should ensure that they contain the correct values before you deploy your application, or you might have to rebuild your application in order to change the configured values.
>
> Before each release of your Android application, you should check that every setting is properly configured.
>
> To configure your Android app:
>
> - On the Project > Options > Application page, provide the icons and images to represent your application.
> - On the Project > Options > Version Info page, increase the version code of your application. Application stores such as Google Play may require that newer versions of your application always have a higher version code than previous versions.
> - On the Project > Options > Uses Permissions page, define the permissions that your application requires to work.
> - On the Project > Options > Provisioning page, select in Target the build configuration that you want to use to deploy your application (for example, Release) and provide a KeyStore file if you have not already created one. This step is necessary in order to install your application in a device that has USB debugging disabled and to distribute your application to others. For more information about keystore files, see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html.

There's also a section on customizing the AndroidManifest.xml file for things like version number and name, required permissions, and so forth.