# How to deploy .ini files in Delphi Android App?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

I cannot find how I distribute my .ini files with my Android app. Not only .ini files, but also example files and help files. I presume there is a way to distribute these files together with the app but I cannot find how to do that with Delphi. I would greatly appreciate a link where this is explained.

Comment: INI files, in Android?  Are you sure you want to use Delphi?;)

Comment: Are you tried the [`Deployment Manager`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Deployment_Manager)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150121/how-to-create-a-delphi-android-application-apk-to-include-files

Comment: @Simon - why not? An INI file is just a plain text file, and TMemIniFile works the same whatever the platform

Comment: @Simon, thanks as well! .ini is a simple and fast way to store config (and other) info, thats why I use it even on Android :-)

Comment: My question seems to be a duplicate question (see Simons comment). What is the correct procedure, delete the question?

Comment: You got an upvote and a favourite, enjoy it ;)  If someone wants to vote to close as duplicate, then so be it.  I would leave it here anyway since the more questions that have solutions, the more chance searchers have of finding it.

Comment: @ChrisRolliston Well, I did put a wink on the end.  I just have memories of the sh*tty hell caused by INI files in the bad old days of Windows.  They are completely unstructured and having win.ini exposed to all was a nightmare.  I just prefer SharedPreferences, pLists and the like because they are simple serialisations of key value pair maps.  Much more "OOP".  I guess it's not really a problem as I assume these INIs are in private files, but I still shudder to think about storing state in an unstructured text file. It just seems, so, last century! ;)  (see, I winked again)

Comment: @Simon - not sure what you mean TBH. An INI file is no less 'structured' than a plist, and I'm struggling to understand why the Android SharedPreferences API is more 'OOP' than the Delphi INI file interface. Moreover, it's easy enough to write TCustomIniFile implementations that wrap the plist API for Apple platforms and the SharedPreferences API for Android (see http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2013/09/12/a-few-xe5-related-bits/).

Comment: This is clearly discussed in the documentation. Start with [this link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Deploying_Cross-Platform_Applications#Deploying_an_Application_for_the_Android_Platform).

Answer (score 2):

In the toolbar go to project and then open deployment. There you can add files to the project!

Answer (score 2):

Full manual about deployment file:

1. on iOS:[Loading and Deploying Files on iOS](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Creating_an_iOS_App#Loading_and_Deploying_Files)
2. on Android: [Loading and Deploying Files on Android](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Creating_an_Android_App#Loading_and_Deploying_Files)

Thank you